# Parameterized queries without user input?

Tags: sql

I'm just double checking here, and I'm sure other people occasionally have this question:

Is there any reason to use a parameterized query when no user input is involved? For example, when putting random strings into an SQL table.

Comment: If you have a completely static piece of SQL, there's no need for a parameterized query. As soon as some part (e.g. string or numeric literals) of a SQL query may vary (no matter whether this is due to user input or a random number generator), using a parameterized query might make sense.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow this variable _is_ user input. Also, sql-parameters can also prevent other issues like data-type conversion or localization issues. It's also often more efficient to use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of safety, yes.  Even if you are sure that the current values are absolutely safe now, can you definitely guarantee that nobody else will make changes, or use the same query for a different purpose, at a future date?

Answer (score 0):

If for no other reason, I like how clean the code is. There are several queries one could theoretically run safely without parameterization, but building the string is so much uglier, and ugly code is hard to understand when maintenance is required.

In C#, for example (a PL/SQL query in this case)

```
String query = @"SELECT thing, stuff
                 FROM table_of_things
                 WHERE thing = :thing
                 OR stuff = :stuff";
```